# Osmosis Installation

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis

I Followed this link [Link<<](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Quick_Install_(Windows)) for Installing OSMOSIS.
But I'm not getting the expected result as shown in the tutorial.
Hoping to get some step by step installing OSMOSIS.
Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

I always used osmosis in Linux, but some time ago I tried to install it in a Windows 8.1 system, so I used this awesome [tutorial](http://learnosm.org/en/osm-data/osmosis/) that is **step by step** tutorial and I really hadn't trouble with the installation.

As I commented in your question I think that you need to reformulate your question and share where's your problem.